# I always get the same result when entering a different input in a if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, input

For example when I enter 1 as input it always returns "I would like to order Spaghetti with meatballs".
What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

```
`order = input("What do you want to order?")
d = "T-bone steak"
e = "fresh salad"
f = "Spaghetti with meatballs"

1 == "meat"
2 == "pasta"
3 == "salad"

if order == 1:
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == 2:
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    print("I would like to order " + f)``
```

Regardless of what I enter as input it always returns that I would like to order Spaghetti with meatballs

Comment: `1 == "meat"` why on earth are you trying to use a number as a variable? and I say trying because you are comparing the numbers to strings, not assigning them.

Comment: @Guy Why shouldn't I use it? What should I use instead?

Comment: For starters you simply can't, it will raise a syntax error. Numbers have their on purpose, you shouldn't use them as variables.

Comment: Can anyone explain what I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s go through the code and debug it to see the problem. I added comments

```py
# get input 
order = input("What do you want to order?")

# assignment 
d = "T-bone steak"
e = "fresh salad"
f = "Spaghetti with meatballs"

# expression (I think you confused this with assignment

1 == "meat" # This will evaluate to False
2 == "pasta" # false
3 == "salad" # false

# so 1 is equal to "meat" is false

# now we check if order equal to integer 1
if order == 1:
    # won’t run as condition is false
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == 2:
    # order is not equal to integer 2
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    # this will execute as all above failed
    print("I would like to order " + f)
```

Possible solution 1:
Assign the expression and use the values directly on the if statement

```py
# assign the expression 

meat_order = order == "meat"
pasta_order = order == "pasta"
salad_order = order == "salad"


if meat_order:
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif salad_order:
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    print("I would like to order " + f)

# use them directly 
not_used_pasta_order = order == "pasta"

if order == "meat":
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == "salad":
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    print("I would like to order " + f)
```

Possible solution 2:
Create a dictionary with the values

```py
…

# assignment 
menu = {1: "meat",
2: "pasta",
3: "salad",
}

# we can now access "meat" with getting 1.

# now we check if order equal to integer 1
if order == menu.get(1):
    # if order is "meat" it will executed 
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == menu.get(2):
    # if order equal to string "pasta" it will execute 
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    # this will execute as all above failed
    print("I would like to order " + f)
```

We could improve our code a little

```py
# get input 
order = input("What do you want to order? ")

# clean order input: remove spaces and lowercase
_order = order.strip().lower()

# assignment

DEFULT_MEAL = "Spaghetti with meatballs"

menu = {"meat": "T-bone steak",
"salad": "fresh salad"}

# get the order if no match get default(the else is if)

get_order = menu.get(_order, DEFULT_MEAL)

# print("I would like to order a " + get_order)

print(f"I would like to order a {get_order}")
```

So we try get the value from dictionary of the order if it exists but if it does return the default;)

## The Problem and Nature of Python

The problem in you code was here

```py
…
1 == "meat"
2 == "pasta"
3 == "salad"
…
```

Due to the forgiving nature of Python, the code execution without warning or issues as the types are not enforced.

You tried to check if `integer` is equal to a `string` and Python was okay with it. All lines will evaluate to `False` and your code execution goes on.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input`, it gives you a string. To compare that with an integer, you have to convert it with `int()` function

```
int_input = int(order)
```

It is a good idea to handle ValueError when changing the variable type as the user can enter unexpected values

```
order = input("What do you want to order?")
try:
    order_int = int(order)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid order number")
```

The other issue is the following part. Python doesn't allow integer values as variable names

```
1 == "meat"
2 == "pasta"
3 == "salad"
```

An alternative would be to put a string before the integer names and use a single equal sign.

```
var_1 = "meat"
var_2 = "pasta"
var_3 = "salad"

if order == var_1:
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == var_2:
    print("I would like to order a " + e)
else:
    print("I would like to order " + f)
```

The best solution is to remove the 3 variables

```
order = input("What do you want to order?")
d = "T-bone steak"
e = "fresh salad"
f = "Spaghetti with meatballs"

if order == "meat":
    print("I would like to order a " + d)
elif order == "pasta":
    print("I would like to order " + e)
else:
    print("I would like to order a " + f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything comiñg from input is a string , so "1" is also string, so you need to wrap the input

```
order = int(input("What do you want to order"))
```